# Gradle's Android's plugin debug output not generated

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Gradle 1.9, the version of the android plugin is 0.7.3. 
As you probably know, the android plugin has two outputs - debug and release.

My project depends on another project.

I've created my own task to execute the unit tests. It depends on the debug output. 
Here's its definition in the `build.gradle` file of the main project.

```
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['tests']
    }
}
dependencies {
    unitTestCompile files("build/classes/debug") //This is the debug output of the main project
    unitTestCompile files("../otherproject/build/classes/debug") //This is the debug output of the other project
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'    
    unitTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
}
configurations {        
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom compile
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runTime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile        
    unitTestEclipseCompile {
        extendsFrom unitTestCompile
        exclude group: "com.google.android", name: "android"
        transitive = false
    }        
}
task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
```

}

The problem is that the debug output is not generated, so when I type `gradle unitTest` in the command line, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

In order for the debug output to be generated, I have to explicitly run `gradle assembleDebug` before I run unitTest.

I've tried the following things, neither of which has worked:

```
unitTest.dependsOn assembleDebug
assembleDebug.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```

The problem doesn't go away regardless of whether the task is out of date or not, So, for example, if I make a slight modification in one of the source files, and then run `gradle unitTest`, the release output is generated with the new `.class` files, but the debug output isn't.

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated version of the Gradle plugin?

Comment: I tried with Gradle 1.12 and android plugin 0.11.1. The problem persists.